# How to implement friendly URLs without breaking images, CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The links on my site are displayed as follows:

```
blog.php?id=Blizzard
```

How can I convert them as follows?

```
blog/Blizzard
```

Using `.htaccess` or PHP?

---

I used the following directive in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ ./blog.php?id=$1
```

But the images, CSS and JavaScript are destroyed!?

Comment: "Destroyed"? That sounds strange. What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the images , css and javascript codes are destroyed

Probably because you are using relative URLs to your static resources. If you are referencing an image as `img/myimage.jpg` then the *browser* is now going to look for `/blog/img/myimage.jpg`, not `/img/myimage.jpg` as before (using your example).

You need to use root-relative URLs (starting with a slash) or absolute URLs (scheme + hostname) to be able to access the resource from different URL-path depths. You can sometimes work around the issue with a `base` element in the `head` section, however, there are caveats with this approach.

See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack that goes into great detail on this exact issue: [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

---

> ```
> RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ ./blog.php?id=$1
> ```

You should remove the `./` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. The dot (to indicate the "current directory") serves no purpose here in the URL-path (it gets resolved away).

You should also include the `L` flag, if you later add other rules.

You also need to ensure that MutliViews is disabled, otherwise, `blog.php` will be "magically" called without the `id` attribute and your script will fail. (MultiViews basically enables extensionless URLs but can cause additional issues.) See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html

Optionally, if you are changing a URL structure, you can also redirect URLs of the form `/blog.php?id=<value>` to `/blog/<value>` in order to preserve SEO and redirect bookmarked links. (But note that you should already be linking to URLs of the form `/blog/<value>` throughout.)

For example

```
# Disable MultiViews
Options -MuliViews

# Redirect "/blog.php?id=<value>" to "/blog/<value>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ /blog/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]

# Rewrite "blog/<value>" to "/blog.php?id=<value>"
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) blog.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Additional notes on the above directives:

- The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that only direct requests are redirected and not rewritten requests by the rewrite that follows.
- The `QSD` flag discards the original query string from the request.
- The `QSA` flag appends (merges) any query string that might be on the original request with the query string being assigned in the substitution. If you are not expecting any query string then remove this flag. eg. A request for `/blog/Blizzard?foo=1` would be internally rewritten to `/blog.php?id=Blizzard&foo=1` only if the `QSA` flag is present.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to create short urls.

examples:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewirteRule sample /sample2.php
```

just 3 line need

```
RewriteEngine On <== Use Rewrite Module
RewriteBase / <==  .htaccess file locate
RewriteRule  <== ShortURL RULE
```

you write

```
RewirteRule sample /sample2.php
```

use http://127.0.0.1/sample

redirect sample2.php

Comment: images , css and javascript codes are destroyed

Comment: `RewirteRule sample /sample2.php` - although a directive like this (if spelt correctly) would result in a rewrite-loop (500 error), since the regex `sample` also matches the target URL `/sample2.php`. The `RewriteBase` directive is also irrelevant in this particular example.