# How to redirect question mark part with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect below example url. but unable to get it right please help me.

suppose url is ***[www.example.com/user?id=abcdef](http://www.example.com/user?id=abcdef)*** (File name user.php)

And i want to redirect it to ***[www.example.com/user/abcdef](http://www.example.com/user/abcdef)***.

i have tried RewriteRule RewriteCond query string as i guess its wrong.

below is what i have written.

***RewriteRule ^user?id=/(.*)?$ user.php?id=$1.***

Please help me to solve it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I match query string variables with mod\_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement friendly URLs without breaking images, CSS and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325941/how-to-implement-friendly-urls-without-breaking-images-css-and-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\w+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?user\.php/?$ /user/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?user/(\w+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It externally redirects requests to URLs that use technical notation and internally rewrites requests using clean syntax.